# Is the microscope that gives these images considered professional?

Tags: microscopy

I bought a digital microscope from `Dinolite`, model `AM73915MZT`, The use of the microscope is for industries like textiles and printing and graphics and for Ophthalmology / Iridology and Pathology *[And as it says on the website that the manufacturer of this microscope is suitable for another wide range of applications]*.

As shown on the manufacturer's website [here](https://www.dino-lite.eu/en/component/eshop/am73915mzt)
The camera has a resolution of `5 Megapixel (2592x1944)`, and the sensor is of the `CMOS` type, with white `LED` lighting, including `Polarizer`.

The microscope costs $1469 before VAT and ancillary aids. From what I understand it is the best and most advanced model of this company.

I took some pictures with him, and at 220x magnification I can't get a sharp enough picture.
Attached an image of the `calibration target` provided by the company along with the microscope.

**Image at a magnification of 220** - 10 barcodes
[image]

**Image at magnification of 50** - 10 barcodes [marked with a red line]
[image]

You can see that the edges of the barcodes at magnification 220 times are not sharp compared to the edges at magnification 50 times.
Does this mean that the microscope is unprofessional or damaged and I need to replace it?
Is it related to `Spherical aberration`?

**EDIT:**

- Both photos were taken with the microscope standing in the best stand of the company, model [RK-10A](https://www.dino-lite.eu/en/component/eshop/rk-10a?Itemid=0).
- If I rotate the **adjustment knob** slightly to
  the right or left, the image only becomes more blurred, which means
  that the position in the image is the maximum sharpness.
- And for that I wonder if a microscope that this is its maximum sharpness - is considered professional.

**EDIT 2:**

Attached image of a scratch:

51x
[image]

228x
[image]

You can see that the 51x image is much sharper and crispier compared to the 228x image, does that mean that the microscope is neither high quality nor professional?

**Razor**

50x
[image]

229x
[image]

Comment: What microscope is "good" depends entirely on the application. "Professional" for *what purpose*? I don't think this site wants to get in to product reviews; these are typically off-topic across the whole SE network with a couple rare exceptions.

Comment: When I buy a camera I can see reviews on whether it is considered professional and whether it produces sharp and beautiful images, no matter what purpose I buy the camera for, is there no definition in the microscope for professional and good only in relation to the purpose?

Comment: For cameras "professional" *also* depends on purpose. This site is not for product reviews, for cameras nor for microscopes.

Comment: But as you stated, it's for textiles and other things unrelated to biology. Just because you intend to use it for biology doesn't make the question as written on-topic.

Comment: Professional is a marketing term. Equipment is not professional. People are. There are some instances where the stuff hobbiests use and make is more meticulous than that of paid professionals, because they can't afford to sit there and obsess. Just consider whether it's good enough and reliable enough for what you need it for.

Comment: Welcome to the site. For a good answer to this question, you need to provide some specifications on the lenses (type [e.g. plan, apo], f., NA.), camera (MP, CCD etc, plus settings [exposure, gain...], separate camera attachment or eyepiece?), microscope (compound, stereo, inverted, etc), and illumination type. Microscopes vary widely in quality and use-case and are not single instruments. Generally you need to pay \$\$\$ for a good one. I routinely use microscopes with lenses that cost in the $4000 range for a single lens, let alone the rest of the 'scope.

Comment: @bob1 I added the details you mentioned, anything else?

Comment: Are you certain you have a blurry image of sharp barcodes and not a sharp image of blurry barcodes?

Comment: @timeskull What do you mean sharp image of blurry barcodes? If you look at the pixels of the image [for example at an 800% zoom in each image viewer] you will see that the blur structure is suitable for lack of focus - lens blur - and not for smeared ink and so on.

Comment: I don't know what technology is used to print the barcodes so I don't know what the edges will look like at high magnification. While I would expect them to be fuzzy, that's not necessarily the case. By my estimation the pixels in the barcodes of your top image are ~5.2 microns. Normal printers / normal paper cannot produce such small features.

Comment: @timeskull What do you think I need to photograph to be sure that if there is blurring it is because of the microscope and not from the observed object? By the way you can also see that the blur in all the barcodes is exactly the same, and as we would expect a blur caused by a lens.

Comment: you could just put a scratch in a glass slide and image that. If the edges of the scratch look sharp, then the calibration barcodes are blurry in reality. Otherwise, the optics of your microscope are the source of the blurriness.

Comment: @timeskull You can also look at the edge of a razor blade. Or a knife has been sharpened and honed by hand on a stone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have bought a basic microscope that is not very good, with probably poor quality lenses and low manufacturing quality - the fact that they don't mention the lens manufacturer is a sign that has cheaper lens(es). A lack of reviews on microscopy sites also indicates that it is not well known. It may be suitable for basic hobbyist use-cases, and depending on what you want to do with it, it may suit you. Despite the blurb on the sales pages, no qualified lab would ever use something like this for pathology or any serious purpose; this is more of a toy than a microscope. Celestron has their "[Handheld Digital Pro Microscope](https://www.celestron.com/products/handheld-digital-microscope-pro)" that's very similar in specs to yours, but retails for about US$ 150 - just for some comparison from a manufacturer that has a good reputation for imaging equipment (telescopes in their case).

I don't think that it is broken, just that you have reached the limits of its magnification capability and if you were able to move it slightly closer or further away from the calibration you would get this in-focus. That it is out of focus indicates either that the stand is off by a bit (you definitely need a stand for that sort of magnification), or that the manufacturing of the microscope is slightly out. At 220x the engineering specs need to be pretty tight to get consistent focus. You won't get that sort of tolerance on a cheaper 'scope.

This is definitely not spherical aberration, as that would manifest as distortion of the image at the edges - a bit like a fish-eye effect. There will be some aberration in the lens (almost impossible to make one without), but this is probably corrected by a combination of software (like in your phone camera) and cropping of the image to only the centre of the image.

As you have brought it recently I would reach out to the supplier and see if you can get a replacement or a return/refund. If you have brought this for business use, get the company to fork out for a decent microscope brand - not only will they be more robust, they will give much better images and come with good technical support.

Good lenses and microscopes are very expensive and you only consistently get good lenses from well known manufacturers (Zeiss, Olympus, Nikon, Leica are the big names). There are some cheaper brands (e.g. Konus, Celestron [these two mostly known for telescopes], Saxon, AmScope)  that make some moderate quality microscopes for not too-high-a price (~$1,500) that make good basic microscopy starter packs. Second-hand microscopes are fairly common on re-selling sites such as eBay too, just make sure you get to see/use it before purchasing.

Without knowing your use-case I can't make any recommendations on what sort of microscope might be useful for you if you were to get a replacement, but your "classic lab microscope" is known as an [Upright or Compound microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_microscope#Compound_microscope), used for looking at small things up-close with [transmitted light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bright-field_microscopy) giving you a flat 2D image. You might be familiar with [stereo-microscopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereo_microscope), which are commonly used for looking at large objects up-close in 3D, usually using reflected light. Stereo-microscopes are also often used for things like soldering electronics and manufacturing quality control in textiles.

Comment: Thanks, I read your answer and I think I missed important details about the stand in my question. I have now edited the question and added these details.

Comment: In that case, given those details, in the absence of vibration, the image is probably as sharp as it gets. As I mentioned in my answer, this is not a professional microscope - those cost much much more than you payed - a medium-high quality single-magnification objective lens costs about the price you payed for the whole set-up!